# Find the original 'dreamy' quote

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge, steganography, poetry, word-sequence

> Grandson, living is key
>   my life was short,
>   but what I did in life,
>   is love it all,
>   so live your life as I have lived mine... full.

I saw another puzzle in this vein and thought I would take it a step further.

**hint #1**

> The cadence of this version doesn't feel the same as the original

**hint #2**

> the original quote was written in an unrhymed iambic pentameter

Comment: After reading some more tags trying to find appropriate tags for this puzzle I realized that **steganography** is appropriate.

Comment: Is it a song lyrics or well known quote?

Answer (score 1):

I will find keywords and using those i will try to make a poem

Poem definitely is about passing a legacy so

> passing, legacy

To pass to grandchild, child must be included so

> child, grandchild

Poem is about loving not about earnings so

> not money, or any things

I googled the keywords and found this

> The greatest legacy one can pass on
> to one's children and grandchildren
> is not money or other material things accumulated in one's life,
> but rather a legacy of character and faith.

[Original source](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/billy_graham_626354?src=t_legacy)

Comment: I feel like this answer needs more explanation. Could you explain in more detail why you believe this is the right answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy I will in my edit

Comment: It's a nice try. I've added a couple hints.